# What should I say in a goodbye email

Tags: professionalism, employer-relations, email

As I move on to my next assignment, I would like to send a goodbye mail to my client as I want to keep the relationship warm. I'd like to keep it brief, simple , appreciative and open to future communication. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Strongly culture dependent

Comment: "So long, and thanks for all the fish"...?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I think many aspects of corporate culture  are becoming more or less the universal , more so, when you work in multinational companies that do business with different countries. Besides, I think the question is specific enough to not have to worry about culture when answering. "brief, simple, appreciative, open to future communication" are all adjectives indicative of what is acceptable in the culture.

Comment: @moonstar2001 what one culture would consider acceptable might be considered as another to be rudely brisk, or extremely convoluted in politeness phrases.  So "the best way" depends on who you write to.

Comment: This question should be reopened.  Many people face this and some good guidelines would be appropriate.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9074/how-do-i-tell-my-boss-i-quit) in my opinion. At the very least, the answers there are going to be quite helpful.

Answer (score 8):

**Make it personal.**
Add a few lines on how someone had helped you during your stay in the organization and graciously thank all )even though there could be some you would not want to). Give your adieu a personal touch. You may even add a few stories of your (good) experiences with the team, the company or the culture.. a touch of subtle humour would work as well.

**Make it easy for your colleagues to contact you.**
Always add your personal contact numbers and/ email address to stay in touch here after. Don't forget to include a link to your LinkedIn Profile...stay connected!

**CC yourself**
Do this on the goodbye letter (on your personal Email ID so those who want to respond back find it easier to do so) and more so for your personal records.

Here is an example of a Goodbye Email I have used previously when leaving a job.

> Dear All,
>
> After an exciting and memorable stint with this company, I am bidding
> farewell next week to this company to pursue other career
> opportunities. As I move on, I would like to take a moment to remember
> and cherish our times together. It’s been great interacting and
> knowing each one of you. Even though I will miss you all here I am
> looking forward to this new challenge and to start a new phase of my
> career.
>
> This is not a goodbye, only a brief parting as I'm sure we will cross paths again.
>
> Do stay in touch.
>
> My personal contacts are:
>
> Email:
>
> Contact phone number:
>
> And you can find me here on LinkedIn
>
> Please do drop in a note with your personal contacts to my Personal Email so we can keep in touch.
>
> Good luck and wish you all the best!
>
> Kindest regards,  Your Name

Comment: Out of curiosity as a non-native speaker - is the example you listed your typical writing style or did you choose a different style for this situation?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That is my native writing style, cross between casual and professional. I don't alter from this or a professional Email. If it was a more casual one there would be a lot more differences.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about addressing an email to a client. Your soon to be former company should have a transition plan for working with that client, and will not want you to complicate that transition. They will also be concerned that you might be trying to convince the client to switch to your new company. Unless there is more than a work relationship involved, the future contact information is not needed. It is possible to have them connect to you via a site like LinkedIn, so that they can be a future reference for employment.

For an email to your co-workers keep it short, simple, and only as a vehicle to provide contact information. Long emails blasted to hundreds of employees will not be read by most of them. Emails that focus on how the employees are like a family...tend to be skimmed over a quickly forgotten.